# While creating Data Extension through SOAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have 2 specific questions w.r.t creating a data extension using SOAP -

1. Can I somehow specify the folder name where I want to create it? Which property/tag I can use?
2. Can I also specify the permissions that this data extension should have? I want to share this data extension with a particular business unit. Can I specify that in my SOAP call?

Answer (score 5):

For the folder, I suggest taking a look at the documentation.  `CategoryID` is the Property that represents the folder.  The [DataFolder](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/datafolder/) Object will give you all of the folders.

[API Objects](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/)

[DataExtension Object](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/dataextension/)

**Sidenote**: Here's a trick for finding the `CategoryID` in the SFMC interface.  If you hover over the folder name, the link in the browser status bar will show the ID.

[image: CategoryID]

Regarding the permissions, I'd suggest just creating the Data Extension in the specific business unit in order to restrict the visibility.  There may be other ways to accomplish that, but I don't think you'll find much info on object-level permissions.